# overloading std::ostream& operator<< in the derived class without static_cast<>

Tags: c++

Is this the only way of overloading the `ostream& operator<<` for a derived class without duplicating code for the base class? Are the casts not something to be avoided?

I don't see any other way, except to define some kind of function in the base class that will represent the data of the base class as something that std::operator<< could "eat up" (like a string?), doing the same thing for the derived class (calling the base class stream representation function within the derived class stream. rep. function of course).

What is the ideal solution to this problem?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
    private: 
        int b_;
    public: 
        Base()
            :
                b_()
        {};

        Base (int b)
            : 
                b_(b)
        {};

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base& b);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Base& b)
{
    os << b.b_; 
    return os;
}

class Derived
:
    public Base
{
    private: 
        int d_;
    public: 
        Derived()
            :
                d_()
        {};

        Derived (int b, int d)
            : 
                Base(b), 
                d_(d)
        {};

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Derived& b);
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Derived& b)
{
    os << static_cast<const Base&>(b) << " " << b.d_; 
    return os;
}



using namespace std;


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    Base b(4);

    cout << b << endl;

    Derived d(4,5);

    cout << d << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is wrong with your solution?

Comment: @K-ballo he wants to avoid the cast I think. There's no problem with it though.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie: Why? What's wrong with the cast? How else would one invoke the `operator <<` for a `Base` ?

Comment: @K-ballo why are you asking me? I just said there's no problem with it.

Comment: :) I asked if an alternative exists xor is necessary in the first place...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well ... casting should be avoided if done in contexts where the result is not correctly defined, but casting into a base is always safe.

It is possible to avoid the explicit cast by considering that a derived reference decays into the base reference, so you can use an  implicit conversion, like in this case:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, const Derived& b)
{
    const Base& bs = b;
    os << bs << " " << b.d_; 
    return os;
}
```

Comment: +1 because you do what I think the questioner really wants, and the motivation for avoiding casts, with a minimal code change. That is, you get the compiler to reject code containing stupid errors like switching `Base` and `Derived` around so that the cast is an unsafe downcast instead of a safe upcast.

Answer (score 5):

```
static_cast<const Base&>(b)
```

is safe and there is nothing incorrect, because every derived class object is also an Base class object and can be treated like one.

Casts are dangerous only when used in a reckless way, You must use casts where they are needed and in a correct manner, that is the very purpose of their provision by the language standard.

Answer (score 1):

You could change things around like this:

```
struct Base {
    int b_;
    void print(ostream &o) { o << b_; }
};

struct Derived : Base {
    int d_;
    void print(ostream &o) {
        Base::print(o);
        o << ' ' << d_;
   }
};

ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, Base &b) {
    b.print(o);
    return o;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &o, Derived &d) {
    d.print(o);
    return o;
}
```

If `Base` had virtual functions (which in this example it doesn't), then `print` could be one of them, and you could get rid of the multiple overloads of `operator<<`.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the casts, you can have your operator call a `writeTo` function that is implemented using the template method pattern.

e.g.

```
class Base {
   public:
       std::ostream& writeTo(std::ostream& ostr) const { os << b_; return this->doWriteTo(os); }
   private:
       int b_;

       virtual std::ostream& doWriteTo(std::ostream& ostr) const = 0; // pure virtual
};


class Derived {
    private:
        int d_;
        virtual std::ostream& doWriteTo(std::ostream& ostr) const {return ostr << d_;}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const Derived& d) {
  return d.writeTo(ostr);
```

}

Actually, using this pattern, you can write `operator<<` once and for all for `Base`:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& ostr, const Base& b) {
  return b.writeTo(ostr);
```

}

This pattern also elminates the need to make `operator<<` a `friend`.